# Why can't my sentinel_1 image dataset be fully mosaicked?

Tags: google-earth-engine, mosaic, sentinel-1

I screened the VH polarization bands of the Sentinel1 images at different dates and mosaicked them, but the final mosaic images obtained were incomplete and only partially.

[image: Screenshot highlighting missing data]

[Here is my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2835835cc78c2aa48df28cc9396d9fe5)

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [
    [
      [110.11523853792353, 31.167878171469763],
      [110.11523853792353, 28.721616208312717],
      [120.16772877229853, 28.721616208312717],
      [120.16772877229853, 31.167878171469763]
    ]
  ])
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

var start_date = ee.Date('2020-06-07');
var finish_date = ee.Date('2020-06-17');
var orbit = 'ASCENDING';

// Get the VV collection.
var collectionS1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  // .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', orbit))
  .filterDate(start_date, finish_date)
  .filterBounds(polygons);

// Get the VH collection.
var collectionVH = collectionS1.select('VH');
var collectionVHmosaic = collectionVH.mosaic();

var VH = ee.Image(collectionVH.median());

Map.centerObject(polygons, 7);
Map.addLayer(VH, {min: -25, max: 5}, 'VH', true);

// Import Tools
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

// Change Folder Name
var folder = 'GEE_EXPORT';

//download to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: collectionVHmosaic,
  description: "VH_T1",
  fileNamePrefix: "GEE_EXPORT",
  scale: 25,
  region: polygons,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Comment: Please put the code in your question, trimmed down to just the important part, I don't think many would follow a hyperlink that isn't *known* to be safe. A screen shot of your results would also help.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your calculation — there simply is not any data available from the satellite that meets the filters you have requested.

Let's take a look at what we get if we don't `filterBounds`, and zoom out:

```js
Map.addLayer(
  ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filterDate(start_date, finish_date)
);
```

[image: Screenshot of map from the above program]

In order to get complete coverage of the `geometry`, you will need to increase your date range until it includes a time when the satellite made a pass over that area.